# separating values in a URL, not with an &

Tags: html, parsing, url, parameters, urlencode

Each parameter in a URL can have multiple values.  How can I separate them?  Here's an example:

```
http://www.example.com/search?queries=cars,phones
```

So I want to search for 2 different things: cars and phones (this is just a contrived example).  The problem is the separator, a comma.  A user could enter a comma in the search form as part of their query and then this would get screwed up.  I could have 2 separate URL parameters:

```
http://www.example.com/login?name1=harry&name2=bob
```

There's no real problem there, in fact I think this is how URLs were designed to handle this situation.  But I can't use it in my particular situation.  Requires a separate long post to say why...  I need to simply separate the values.

My question is basically, is there a URL encodable character or value that can't possibly be entered in a form (textarea or input) which I can use as a separator?  Like a null character?  Or a non-visible character?

**UPDATE**: thank you all for your very quick responses.  I should've listed the same parameter name example too, but order matters in my case so that wasn't an option either.  We solved this by using a %00 URL encoded character (UTF-8 \u0000) as a value separator.

Comment: How are the values being input by the user in the first place?  Some number of text fields?

Comment: Why don't you just url encode the value of your parameters? If they enter %20 then the % will get encoded so it won't actually cause a problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: values are being input by standard html form elements.  The problem with %20 is not that they would enter %20, it's that they would enter what %20 represents (a space I think).

Comment: It's mentioned in a comment below that "this is for a standard widget mechanism that will be used in a **thousand different situations**." - it should be noted that `%00` (encoded NULL) in the query string will be actively blocked on some servers as a security safe guard.

Answer (score 15):

The standard approach to this is to use the same key name twice.

```
http://www.example.com/search?queries=cars&queries=phones
```

Most form libraries will allow you to access it as an array automatically. (If you are using PHP (and making use of `$_POST/GET` and not reinventing the wheel) you will need to change the name to `queries[]`.)

Comment: I mentioned in my update that you're correct this was an option too, but in my case I really need to just separate values within a parameter value.  Order matters and parameters with the same name will have different separated values (sometimes with just a different order)

Answer (score 2):

You can give them each the *same* parameter name.

```
http://www.example.com/search?query=cars&query=phones
```

The average server side HTTP API is able to obtain them as an **array**. As per your question history, you're using JSP/Servlet, so you can use [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) for this.

```
String[] queries = request.getParameterValues("query");
```

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work for me either because order matters, I explained in another reply in slightly more detail.  I'm happy to see you remember my other questions though!  Thank you for all your help!  I did find a good solution, I think, to this issue (question updated).

Answer (score 2):

Just URL-encode the user input so that their commas become *%2C*.

Answer (score 1):

Come up with your own separator that is unlikely to get entered in a query.  Two underscores `'__'` for example.

Comment: That's essentially what I was asking for, but I wanted something that would be impossible to get entered into a standard html form element.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do something like "||"?  Anyone who types that into a search area probably fell asleep on their keyboard :}  Then just explode it on the backend.

Comment: maybe you're right :).  But this is for a standard widget mechanism that will be used in a thousand different situations.

Comment: Ahhh, ok that changes things. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

easiest thing to do would be to use a custom separator like [!!ValSep!!].